# Another definition for the support of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $S_X$ be the support of a random variable $X$,
\begin{equation}
S_X = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : F(x + \varepsilon) - F(x - \varepsilon) > 0 \mbox{ for all } \varepsilon > 0\}\mbox{,}
\end{equation}
being $F : \mathbb{R} \to [0 , 1]$ the distribution function associated with $X$. Defining the family
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C} = \{C \subset \mathbb{R} : C \mbox{ is a closed set and } P_X(C) = 1\}\mbox{,}
\end{equation}
where $P_X$ is the probability induced by $X$, I want to show that
\begin{equation}
S_X = \bigcap_{C \in \mathcal{C}} C\mbox{.}
\end{equation}
I have already proved that $S_X$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, so I have only to show that $S_X \subset C$ for all $C \in \mathcal{C}$, though my attemps are not successful. Could you give me a hint? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** It will suffice to assume $\exists C \in \mathcal{C}, x \in S_X$ s.t. $x \notin C$ and derive a contradiction. Since $C$ is closed, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. the interval $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\notin C$.

Comment: I agree, but how can I continue the proof?

Comment: Okay. Calling $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, we also have that $(x - \delta , x + \delta] \subset C^c$, so the contradiction is the next:
\begin{equation}
0 < F(x + \delta) - F(x - \delta) = P_X((x - \delta , x + \delta]) \leq P_X(\mathbb{R} \setminus C) = 1 - P_X(C) = 0\mbox{.}
\end{equation}
Do you agree? Thank you.

Comment: @joseabp91 Yes, looks good